# ListView realtime datasets up to 1000 items per second slows everything down

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, real-time-data

I have a ListView to observe messages between different electronic devices in a car.
For some parts i only get a few datasets per second but on others this could go up to 1000.

The ListView is only part of my App, the other part is working with the massive amount of data quite well.

i use a customized ArrayAdapter with following getView:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    itemp = items.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        tvs = new TextView[7];
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mycontext).inflate(container, parent,false);
        tvs[0] = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rd_l_c_messzeit);
        tvs[1] = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rd_l_c_frameid);
        tvs[2] = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rd_l_c_can);
        tvs[3] = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rd_l_c_dlc);
        tvs[4] = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rd_l_c_typ);
        tvs[5] = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rd_l_c_data);
        tvs[6] = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rd_l_c_datum);

        convertView.setTag(tvs);
        convertView.setEnabled(false);
    }else {
        tvs=(TextView[]) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (itemp != null) {
        strings = itemp.getStrings();
        if (container == R.layout.rawdata_list_container) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                if (tvs[i] != null) {
                    tvs[i].setText(strings[i]);
                }
            }
            tvs[3].setText(strings[3].substring(1));

        }

    }
    return convertView;
}
```

My Rowlayout is just 7 Textviews so my Holder is a  TextView Array
items is my ArrayList with DataItems where the getStrings() returns a Stringarray size 7

The contents of the StringArray are defined in background threads which are tested and run smoothly.

Calling 1000 times notifyDataSetChanged() causes a complete stop and my UI is not responsive so i buffered the DataItems in a backgroundthread and update the real adapter only 5 times a second.

```
Runnable updaterun=new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        for(RawdataItem rdi:templist)
        {
            tracelist.add(1,rdi);
            if(tracelist.size()>500)
            {
                tracelist.remove(500);
            }

        }

        for(RawdataItem rdi:templistlight)
        {
            count = 0;
            newtrl=true;
            for (RawdataItem r : tracelistlight) {
                if (rdi.lid == r.lid) {
                    tracelistlight.set(count,rdi);
                    newtrl=false;
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
            if(newtrl) {
                tracelistlight.add(rdi);
                    Collections.sort(tracelistlight);           
            }
        }
        update_rdl();
        templist.clear();
        templistlight.clear();
        updatehandler.postDelayed(updaterun, 200);
    }
};
```

the tracelist is to display all items and the light list is to display every id only once
update_rdl just calls notifidatasetchanged for both lists;

I would be glad for any and all help you could give me.

Comment: please post the scheduling you are using like the code with notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: the templist and templistlight is filled with RawdataItems in a background workerthread.  the tracelist and tracelistlight are the ArrayLists i use for my adapter. notifyDataSetChanged() is called in update_rdl() which was a convenient method from earlier versions

Comment: oh and updatehandler is running on the UI-Thread